# Фильтр таблицы по другой таблице

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. Есть две таблицы. Titles и Genres

**Titles:**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
+----+
```

**Genres:**

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |  title_id  |  genre_id  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |     1      |     1      |
|  2 |     1      |     2      |
|  3 |     2      |     1      |
|  4 |     2      |     3      |
|  5 |     3      |     4      |
|  6 |     3      |     2      |
|  7 |     4      |     5      |
|  7 |     4      |     6      |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Согласно им title с номером 2 соответствуют два genre (1 и 3)

Мне необходимо вывести список titles у которых, например, genre одновременно равен 1 и 3 **ИЛИ** одновременно не равен 2 и 4

Пробую такой запрос: работает для условия IN. Можно ли написать подобный для NOT IN, чтобы запрос особо не менялся и мог выполниться при условии, что часть IN тоже присутствует. Возможно ли построить такой запрос?

```
SELECT t.id FROM titles t 
LEFT JOIN genres g ON t.id = g.title_id 
WHERE g.genre_id IN(1, 2) 
GROUP BY t.id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT g.genre_id) = 2 
ORDER BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, на какой результат ты рассчитываешь в результате выполнения твоей логики:

1. для единицы это будет (да или нет)и(не(нет или нет)) = да
2. для двойки (нет или да)и(не(да или нет)) = нет
3. для тройки (нет или нет)и(не(нет или нет)) = нет
4. для четверки (нет или нет)и(не(нет или да)) = нет

То есть фактически `g.genre_id IN(1, 2) AND g.genre_id NOT IN(2, 4)` ты выбираешь строки, где `genre_id=1`.

**Обновление**

Ты копаешь не в ту сторону. Твой запрос не может просмотреть несколько строк таблицы, он всегда будет смотреть только на одну (в которой, естественно, genre_id не может одновременно равняться 2 и не равняться 2). Чтобы искать совпадение двух жанров, надо умножить таблицу на саму себя

По твоей обновленной логике, получается, что ответом на запрос является сложение множества (1,2) и (2), что равняется (1,2).

(1,2) так как это те тайтлы, в которых не встречается 2 и 4 одновременно.
(2) так как это тот тайтл, в котором встречается 1 и 3 одновременно.

Такие данные, по твоему разумению, должны были получиться в результате выполнения запроса?

Comment: Прошу прощения, скорректировал вопрос и исправил ошибку с двойкой. Мне нужен запрос, который бы сработал одновременно и при возможности присутствия IN условия, и при возможности присутствия NOT IN условия.

Comment: Нашел уникальный запрос, который выполнится в любом случае, какими бы не были условия. Выдаст все titles, у которых genres и 1 и 3.
При этом отбросит те из них, у которых genres и 2 и 4

Ответ на мой вопрос:

SELECT t.id FROM titles t
WHERE

(SELECT count(g.id) FROM genres g WHERE t.id = g.title_id AND g.genre_id = 1) > 0

AND (SELECT count(g.id) FROM genres g WHERE t.id = g.title_id AND g.genre_id = 3) > 0

AND (SELECT count(g.id) FROM genres g WHERE t.id = g.title_id AND g.genre_id = 2) = 0

AND (SELECT count(g.id) FROM genres g WHERE t.id = g.title_id AND g.genre_id = 4) = 0